# How to iterate through an array in concourse

Tags: yaml, concourse, concourse-task

As far as I've searched I don't see any documentation for loops and arrays for Concourse CI.

I'm trying to migrate a job from Jenkins to CI and the snippet of my Jenkins file

```
def folders = [
    "roller",
    "auth",
    "Django",
    "gitlab",
    "Drone",

]
        stage('tests & conv') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                not {
                    branch 'master'
                }
            }
        steps {
                script {
                    parallel folders.collectEntries {
                         [
                             "tests ${i}" : {
                                 stage("Test ${i}") {
                                     sh "make ${i}"
                                 }
                             },
                             "conv ${it}" : {
                                 stage("Test ${i}") {
                                     sh "make run ${i} "
                                 }
                             },
                         ]
                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I replicate the same in the Concourse pipeline.

I can define an array like below but unsure how to iterate thru them.

```
folders:
  - roller
  - auth
  - Django
  - gitlab
  - Drone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the complete answer but should definitely start you off running in the right direction.
You can in effect do what you need using [Carvel YTT](https://carvel.dev/ytt/) which automates the YAML creation. There is also a very handy playground on that site where you can check your workings, and it will show you what the generated YAML will look like.

Example `vars.yaml`:

```
#@data/values
---
folders:
 - name: roller
 - name: auth
 - name: Django
 - name: gitlab
 - name: Drone-runtime
```

Example `schema.yaml` would then be:

```
#@data/values-schema
---
folders:
 - name: ""
```

Your starting concourse Carvel-ytt `pipeline.yaml` could be:

```
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")
#@ load("@ytt:struct", "struct")

#@ folders = []
#@ for f in data.values.folders:
#@   folders.append(struct.make(name = f.name))
#@ end

#@ def task_make(folder):
task: #@ folder.name + "make-task"
image: alpine
config:
  platform: linux
  params:
    NAME: #@ folder.name
  run: 
    path: /bin/sh
    user: root
    args: 
      - -exec
      - |
        make "$NAME"
#@ end

#@ def task_make_run(folder):
task: #@ folder.name + "make-run-task"
image: alpine
config:
  platform: linux
  params:
    NAME: #@ folder.name
  run: 
    path: /bin/sh
    user: root
    args: 
      - -exec
      - |
        make run "$NAME"
#@ end

#@ def job(folder):
name: #@ folder.name
plan:
  - get: alpine
  - #@ task_make(folder)
  - #@ task_make_run(folder)
#@ end

resources:
  - name: ytt
    type: registry-image
    source:
      repository: taylorsilva/carvel-ytt
      tag: 0.36
  - name: cicd-source
    type: git
    icon: bitbucket
    source:
      uri: ((git-source-ssh-url))/((this-repo)).git
      branch: main
      private_key: ((key.git-key))
  - name: alpine
    type: registry-image
    icon: docker
    source:
      repository: alpine
      tag: '3.15.5'

jobs:
  - name: configure-self
    plan:
      - in_parallel:
          - get: ytt
          - get: cicd-source
            trigger: true
      - task: generate-jobs
        image: ytt
        config:
          platform: linux
          inputs:
            - name: ci-source
          outputs:
            - name: pipeline
          run:
            path: /bin/sh
            user: root
            args:
              - -exc
              - |
                ytt -f ./cicd-source --output-files pipeline
      - set_pipeline: job-manager
        file: pipeline/pipeline.yaml
  #@ for folder in data.values.folders:
  - #@ job(folder)
  #@ end
```

Now in the `pipeline.yaml` there is a lot going on here that is out of scope of your OP, but pretty neat. We use taylorsilva's [carvel-ytt](https://hub.docker.com/r/taylorsilva/carvel-ytt) image and this creates the `pipeline.yaml` that we point the concourse `set-pipeline` command to generate the all the jobs. This `self-configure` job will automatically trigger and update itself when you update its SCM. If you have any secret management set up then you can substitute the `((variable references))`, otherwise replace them directly with what you need.

- Note: that you may need to change the commands run in the tasks depending on your need.
- Note: You should update your images to pull from a local repository rather than direct from dockerhub each time.